# selective printing

Tags: awk

I have large files that I want to do some selecting printing on. I want to find a line based on a pattern match and print this line, and all following lines up to the end of the file. I would use sed, however, the match is only based on the first and second column.

```
awk '{if($1=="XYZ" && $2=="GT") print $0}' in.file > out.file
```

How can I change the above to also print all lines following the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a printing flag:

```
awk '$1=="XYZ" && $2=="GT" { f = 1 } f' in.file > out.file
```

The `f` is set to 1 when the two conditions are met. The lone `f` at the end of the script invokes the default block `{ print $0 }` when 1.

Answer (score 1):

Or try using a range pattern:

```
awk '$1=="XYZ" && $2=="GT",end' file
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, your `sed` approach was fine.  If the separator is `;`:

```
sed -n -e '/^XYZ;GT;/,$p' your_file
```